# Why can’t I edit this question but I can still edit others?

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

I don’t have the magically 2,000+ to actually edit content independently, but why can’t I edit this quite obviously messed up post:

[Cannot access the Internet even though it shows to be connected on Ubuntu 14.04](https://superuser.com/questions/823804/i-have-installed-ubantu-14-04-lts-i-got-wired-connection-but-i-can-not-access)

Screenshot below: Note the greyed out `edit` link. Active for me on other posts.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a pending suggested edit on the post. If you have less than 2000 rep, you can suggest edits, but you cannot suggest additional edits to a post that already has pending suggested edits.